# Can't update MYSQL database with new value from URL (using GET)

Tags: php, mysql

I need my database to update 'SID' row according to variable that it gets from url.

Right now, if I have link like this: http://localhost/index.php?sid=fdskdsfkl202klfdfkldsfsdlk2

It will show in SID input field this: fdskdsfkl202klfdfkldsfsdlk2

But when I press register, it always show: 'NoSidAttached' in the database.

I am missing something in the code but can't find what...

Full code from registration page including HTML and PHP.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variable sID from URL
if(isset($_GET['sid'])) {
   $sid = $_GET['sid'];
 } else {
   $sid = 'NoSidAttached';
}

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, sid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_sid);

            // Set parameters
            $param_sid = $sid;
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;   
                header("location: welcome.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>SID</label>
                <input type="text" name="sid" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is right and working with $_GET in my system. 
but you can not find any solutions can try $_REQUEST instead of $_GET

Comment: Also look at how your web server is configured.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
```

Your form uses `method="post"`, meaning the 'sid' will be in $_POST in this case. As mentioned in the comment, `$_REQUEST` as a combination of `$_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE` is the best way to cover both cases. Or change the method of the form to "get".

One more thing:

```
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                session_start();
```

Please get rid of this second session_start(). Session is started before any output happens (you already did this correctly at the beginning of the file), this subsequent session_start does not do anything.